# Is there up-to-date (circa 2070) information about the AGS / ADL?

Tags: campaign-settings, shadowrun-sr4, background

I'm looking for updated (2070) background information about the **ADL** (*Alianz Deutscher Länder*, aka whats left of former Germany and its surroundings), I think it's called **AGS** (*Allied German States*) in the English version.

I'm especially interested in Hamburg and the Meta-Human states. Everything from official sourcebooks to supplements and unofficial info (fan made) would be interesting, even recent Novells or stories.

*I'm trying to prepare for a smuggler setting, with lot's of north sea pirating and land runs all over the AGS (the setting is kinda vehicle and anti-surveillance equipment heavy and focuses more on contraband handling than classic shadowrunning). I'm looking primarily for informations about locations, places and neighborhoods and everything else that helps creating a surrounding for the harbors, trade post and smuggling routes.*

Comment: Comments purged.  Question is fine; if it was too broad it would have a lot more answers wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found so far:

### Setting Sourcebooks

- **AGS**: There is *Deutschland in den Schatten* (the translated version called *Germany Sourcebook*), which is really great but timeline wise around SR2 (2053). It got a wealth of information, the only bad thing is that it is mostly outdated.
- **AGS**: *Brennpunkt: ADL* complement *Deutschland in den Schatten* with background info about politics, lifestyle, sport and the like. Also details about police, military and magic in the AGS. Setting wise the time line gets updated to SR3 (2063). I haven't read it so far, but the critics are favourable. Sadly there's no info about neighborhoods, locations and the like.
- **AGS**: I also found a chapter on the AGS in *Sixth World Almanac*, which seems to me to be the most recent source of info, but it isn't that detailed, more of an overview.
- AGS - **Hamburg**: And a little bit more on Hamburg in *Runner Havens*, which seems to be a quick summary of the Hamburg part in the german *Schattenstädte*.
- AGS - **Hamburg**: There also is the above mentioned *Schattenstädte* from the german publisher Pegasus. Which has a lot more detailed info about Hamburg (along with other info from *Runners Havens*). Good stuff but not that detailed as *Germany Sourcebook*.
- AGS - **Frankfurt**: The german translation of *Corporate Enclaves*, called *Konzenenklaven*, contains information about the 'Groß-Frankfurt' sprawl and stuff impotant to it, like 'AG Chemie', the 'Sternschutz' and more.
- AGS - **Rhein/Ruhr**: *Rhein-Ruhr-Megaplex* got information on the huge Rhein-Ruhr sprawl, from Pegasus.
- AGS - **Berlin**: Pegasus also released a source book about Berlin called *Berlin*.
- AGS - **München**: *München Noir*, also from Pegasus, a source book about Munich.
- AGS - **SOX**: Lots of information about the *SOX* a contaminated area between germany and france, Pegasus again.
- AGS - **Corporations**: The german version of *Corporate Guide* called *Konzerndossier* contains additional information about corporations in the AGS.

It seems that there will be no SR4 version of a AGS sourcebook. Instead Pegasus adds information on the AGS to the sourcebooks they translate.

Answer (score 0):

For now I only got the information on the german versions published by Heyne (1991-2006 1-65, and some collections later on), FanPro (since 1997) and Phönix.

Note: I havn't read all of them, so the information on setting and timeline is mostly from the book summaries or reviews. If you got information about those, please add.

### Fiction

**SR2**

- 10: *Das zerrissene Land* (Deutschland in den Schatten - 1)
- 11: *Die Augen des Riggers* (Deutschland in den Schatten - 2)
- 12: *Die Graue Eminenz* (Deutschland in den Schatten - 3)

**SR3**

- 45: *TAKC 3000* (Schattenjäger - 1)
- 46: *Nachtstreife*
- 47: *Gottes Engel* (Schattenjäger - 2)
- 48: *Aeternitas* (Schattenjäger - 3)
- 49: *Auf dem Sprung*(Nordlichter - 1)
- 50: *Töne der Unendlichkeit* (Nordlichter - 2)
- 51: *Sturmvogel* (Schattenläufer - 1)
- 52: *Elementares Wissen* (Nordlichter - 3)
- 53: *05:58* (Schattenläufer - 2)
- 54: *Jede Wette* (Schattenläufer - 3)
- 56: *Altes Eisen*
- 61: *Flynns Weg*

**SR4**

- 63: *Matrixfeuer* (collection of shortstories)
- 65: *Im Namen des Herrn*
- 69: *Feuerzauber*
- 70: *Im Fadenkreuz*
- 76: *Böses Erwachen*
- 77: *Der Schattenlehrling*
- 82: *Digitaler Alptraum*

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you append this to your previous answer?

Comment: Thought it would be easier for people to edit and add information to it.

Comment: If you want other people to be able to edit an answer, check the "community wiki" checkbox down in the lower right and then anyone can.